# How To Iterate Through All My Ruby on Rails Users In A Rake File?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to write a rake task that iterates through all my users in a Ruby on Rails project then makes changes to them. I know enough Ruby to make this work for one user, and I've done this successfully, now I want to iterate through all users and do the same.

This is my current code:

```
namespace :abc do 
desc "Used to generate a new daily log"

STARTING_DATE = Date.new(2017, 04, 03)

task :create_post => :environment do

User.all.each do |currentUser|
     Post.create!(content: "RAKED") if Date.today >= STARTING_DATE
end
puts "It worked yo"     
end

end
```

The problem area is the iterating through the users. The error I get as its currently written is: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist, User can't be blank"

Does anyone know the proper Ruby way of iterating through users like this?

Also, I've tried the following code:

```
User.all.each do |currentUser|
 puts currentUser.name
end
```

And it will correctly display the name of each User. So it perhaps has something to do with my Users interacting with the Post.create! line?

Thanks!

Comment: User.all.each instead of @users.each

Comment: I also tried this, it gives the error: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist, User can't be blank"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your codes for `Post` model, I guess it has an association like:

`belongs_to: user`

That is why it gives error `User must exist` . Check [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/18233) link for the Github discussion. It was added in Rails 5 so I suppose, that is your Rails version too.

Add association like this `belongs_to :user, optional: true` to make this function like it used to be before Rails 5.

For the error `User can't be blank`, I think it is because you have added another extra validation to your `Post` model, like below:

`validates :user, :presence => true`

So if a user foreign key is not mandatory for every Post record then you have to remove this validation and use `optional: true` as I suggested above. Otherwise If you keep this validation or not going to use `optional` flag then you have to supply a `User` to every post you create. Maybe you can try modifying your code like below:

```
User.all.each do |currentUser|
     Post.create!(content: "RAKED", user: currentUser) if Date.today >= STARTING_DATE
end
```

On a side note: Depending on your database size(no. of Users record), you should avoid `User.all` since it will load all users to memory and in production, it may consume too much memory. [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_in_batches) can be a good alternative.

Comment: Thanks, just using the final code you suggested worked without me needing to change any of the validations :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you haven't initialised `@users` to refer to all your users.

Try adding `@users = User.all` before the for-each loop.

Comment: Even doing User.all.each I get the error: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User must exist, User can't be blank"

Comment: Hmm.. Try adding an association to Post, like `belongs_to :user, optional: true`.

Comment: I already had belongs_to but not the optional part. Adding the optional part removes the "User must exist" error but I still get the error: "ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: User can't be blank"

Comment: If you just try `puts currentUser.user_id` instead of the Post.create, does that work?

Comment: Hi, thanks! I tried this and it does indeed work. However, I'm not sure why my Post.create line isn't working because I had it working for an individual user before, its just iterating through all users that seems to cause problems.

Comment: @Andrew maybe there is a validation on a post that check presence of the user